# Set padding for a div with class name use javascript

Tags: javascript, css, padding, var

I use this javascript code :

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function () {
        $(".container").delay(2000).fadeIn(500);
        var myElement = document.querySelector("#bl-main > section");
        myElement.style.bottom = "300px";
    });
</script>
```

It's worked.
But I edit to this code (for set bottom positon of a div/section = header picture + headermenu) :

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function () {
        //document.getElementById("bl-main").style.bottom = "300px";
        var headerroot = document.getElementById('headerroot').style.height;
        var headMenu = document.getElementById('headMenu').style.height;
        var tru = headerroot + headMenu + "px";
        $(".container").delay(2000).fadeIn(500);
        var myElement = document.querySelector("#bl-main > section");
        myElement.style.bottom = tru;
    });
</script>
```

Something's wrong and the code not work @_@
What's wrong in my code ?
Thanks.

Comment: if you are using jQuery, why are you still using javascript function in it? document.getElementById("a") -> $("#a") ?

Comment: `style.height` will return inline css height if any!

Comment: @TreeNguyen, Is that the problem ? That seems out of context of the question..

Comment: Can you share your HTML or Fiddle ?

Comment: @RayonDabre yah I know. Just want to mention to him before checking the error :)

Comment: Tree Nguyen : As you can see, I removed it in my code. And I think it's not issue now :( . I think something's wrong in my code, not it.  
@Rayon Dabre : I don't know to use Fiddle T_T ... HTML is too long. So, I wanna set bottom postion a section of a div (div ID and class is "bl-main" and I wanna set postion for section "bl-main > section" = headerbanner height + headermenu height. Then I make a bad code and I can't fixed it @_@

Answer (score 3):

> `style.height` will return value associated with `px` which is string hence `+` will concat them instead of `addition`

```js
function changePosition() {
 var headerroot = document.getElementById('headerroot').style.height;
 var headMenu = document.getElementById('headMenu').style.height;
 var tru = parseInt(headerroot) + parseInt(headMenu) + 'px';
 var myElement = document.querySelector("#test");
 myElement.style.bottom = tru;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerroot" style="height: 50px"></div>
<div id="headMenu" style="height: 100px"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="changePosition()">Change</button>
<div id="test" style="background: green;position: absolute">Test Data</div>
```

Comment: I can see it work but when I apply to my code. It's not work. I think I have 2 problem with this code.  
1/ I wanna apply this to all section in bl-main div. querySelector can work when I select a class, not a ID ?  
2/ getElementID.style.height work only when that component was set height ? The trouble is headerroot and headMenu have no fix height T_T (If it fixed height, I will set padding to css code, no need js T_T)

Comment: This question does not expect what you are stating in comment. Kindly post another question so that you will find suitable solution!

Answer (score 1):

I am kind of confuse at first about what you are trying to do. So I will leave 2 ideas here in case you need either of them

If you are planning to apply new style like : padding {0px 0px 10px 10px} then it should look like this

```
var tru = headerroot + "px " + headMenu + "px"; //get the number and put the "px" word after the number
```

If the case is you want to add 2 number for the new style, try doing this first:

```
var tru = headerroot + headMenu; //this will do the addition
tru = tru + "px"; //this will concat with px -> new style
```

The reason is: javascript is not strict about type so you can basically add anything to each other. So when you doing headerroot + headMenu + "px", it thinks that you are trying to create a new string, not adding number and put "px at the end.

Comment: This will do string `concatenation` not addition!

Comment: @RayonDabre Yes. That what's I mean. At the end it should look something like "12px 12px". And that's the new style to apply

Comment: He is applying `myElement.style.bottom`..Are you sure what you are saying ?

Comment: @RayonDabre hi. i have just figured out that I got thing a little bit wrong :). Have just edited :)

Comment: OP has already done that: `var tru = headerroot + headMenu + "px";`

Comment: @RayonDabre if he does that, it will concatenation the string. but if he separates it, it will do the addition and then concat :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94466/discussion-between-tree-nguyen-and-rayon-dabre).

Answer (score 1):

You could try `.clientHeight` or `.offsetHeight` instead of `.style.height`

```
var headerroot = document.getElementById('headerroot').clientHeight;
        var headMenu = document.getElementById('headMenu').clientHeight;
```

> The offsetHeight property is similar to the clientHeight property, but it returns the height including the padding, scrollBar and the border.